# What set of criteria led Hamilton to discover the quaternions?

Tags: mathematics, abstract-algebra, quaternions

Frobenius's theorem states that the only finite-dimensional, associative division algebras over $\mathbb R$ are: $\mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb H$ (where the last of these are the quaternions). So one might be led to think that:

- Hamilton discovered the notion of a finite-dimensional unital algebra over $\mathbb R$. These things are sometimes called hypercomplex number systems.
- Hamilton discovered that some of these algebras are associative, and some are not.
- Hamilton discovered that some algebras are division algebras, while most are not.

Putting these together, Hamilton might have set about to find a larger finite-dimensional, associative, division algebra than $\mathbb C$, and eventually arrived at $\mathbb H$. This would be quite impressive as I *think* that the above three notions did not get studied until after Hamilton presented the quaternions as the first non-trivial hypercomplex number system.

You see, some explanation is badly needed for why Hamilton dismissed straightforward generalisations of $\mathbb C$ like $\mathbb C \oplus \mathbb R$ in his project to generalise $\mathbb C$, and instead settled on a *non-commutative* 4-dimensional algebra whose defining relation is the arguably cryptic $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1$. What criteria was he looking to satisfy?

PS: *A bonus question would be to explain how Gauss independently discovered the quaternions. Should this be asked as a separate question?*

Comment: I don’t think it is correct to say that Hamilton discovered that there are both associative and non-associative algebras.  It is true that Hamilton introduced the term *associative* in an 1844 update to his 1843 paper on quaternions.  This update was coincidental with Hamilton’s colleague Graves’ discovery of octonions - a non-associative algebra, unlike Hamilton's quaternions which are associative.  This suggests that Graves may have been the first to discover that there were both associative and non-associative algebras.

Comment: Here is a [reference for Hamilton's introduction of the term *associative*](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/a/).

Comment: @nwr I was convinced it had something to do with (what became) Frobenius's theorem. This forces associativity to be one of the criteria. But he went via the normed unital algebra root instead where associativity is not a criterion. Hurwitz's theorem shows that this would've led him to the quaternions, and if he kept going, the octonions, and nowhere else.

Comment: None of the above. Hamilton was not thinking in terms of these latter day abstractions. Some were, at best, an afterthought, and the rest did not move him at all. He was looking for a way to "multiply triples", and it hit him how to multiply quadruples instead when he was walking across the Brougham Bridge in October 1843. In excitement he carved the formulas into the stone with his knife, reportedly, and there is a [memorial plaque](https://twitter.com/mathematicsucl/status/1184464891010265088?lang=en) there to mark the occasion.

Comment: @Conifold what does "multiply triples" mean? There are lots of ways of "multiplying triples". Your comment does not explain why $\mathbb C \oplus \mathbb R$ doesn't count as a way of "multiplying triples", and so does nothing to answer the question

Comment: The question is misguided to begin with, Hamilton  was interested in geometric interpretation, not abstract algebra. Thinking up refined options made of concepts developed after the fact and then looking for explanations why discoverers "chose" one rather than another is one of the reasons we have in circulation so many concocted myths. History does not unfold according to "rational reconstructions" that people find "natural" two centuries later, it is a messy affair, and it does not offer neat explanations for posterity's benefit.

Comment: @Conifold I deleted my previous comments to you. I'll summarise my point of view as follows: The usual account of how Hamilton discovered the quaternions is vague. "Multiplying triples" is super vague because there are simple ways of doing it, and the quaternions are anything but simple. The question is of present mathematical interest. You're the one who's misguided in thinking I ruled out geometric constructions of the quaternions, which I never did. I presumed an abstract algebraic origin was more likely because the "most natural" and complete definitions of the quaternions work that way

Comment: If you are interested in how Hamilton *himself* described his thought process in notebooks, letters and lectures see [van der Waerden, Hamilton's Discovery of Quaternions](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689449). He wanted to multiply triplets term by term and have the length of the product vector equal the product of the lengths. In trying to understand historical developments it generally helps to forget about modern concepts, context and what they make "most natural", and look at what was current at the time. The past linked things differently than a backprojection from the present.

Comment: @Conifold That's precisely what I said in my answer. And in modern terminology, we call that a normed unital algebra.

Comment: @Conifold This theorem shows that under those criteria (remember my question asked for criteria?) Hamilton's discovery was inevitable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras) . Different criteria would not have led to the quaternions, given that they're a needle in a haystack when it comes to algebras

Comment: @Conifold I apologise for another one of my deleted comments. The points you make against "back-projection" are obvious and you don't need to spell them out to me. I have *not* made the mistake you're accusing me of. I explicitly acknowledged the problem with assuming that Hamilton had a good grasp of concepts in abstract algebra in my question statement *before* you left your comment assuming I didn't: "This would be quite impressive as I think that the above three notions did not get studied until after Hamilton presented the quaternions as the first non-trivial hypercomplex number system."

Comment: What *we* call a "normed unital algebra", "associative division algebra", etc., comes with all the modern concepts and connotations that did not exist at the time. Indeed, you bring them up explicitly as motivations for the question about "straightforward generalisations". It was not "inevitable" that those exact frameworks should develop from what was in place in Hamilton's time, what *he* traded in could be recombined and abstracted in various other ways. It is all the more disappointing that even after looking at all that you still formulate reasons then within context imported from today.

Comment: @Conifold I'm convinced you have a serious problem with reading comprehension. I think you've got some problem with me using the word "inevitable" when there's nothing wrong with me using it. What's *inevitable* is that *those criteria* would lead to the quaternions, because that's a mathematical fact and not a historical one. I already linked you to Hurwitz's theorem but I'm convinced that you don't get it.

Comment: Would they? It was "inevitable" that he wouldn't give up, that he would not stick to triples and end up with de Morgan's multiplication, that it would hit him to switch to quadruples on the Brougham Bridge. Or, since triples were also one of his "criteria", perhaps it was "inevitable" that he would realize impossibility and move on. What I object to is not so much your specific assertions as the entire ahistorical frame of mind where modern mathematical facts induce a march towards their "inevitable" formulation, and history is then queried through that prism.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for your patient explanation. I see what you mean. I suppose I asked the question not because I was interested in complete historical accuracy, but because I want to understand how one might be led to the 4ions as a product of some simple question, problem or investigation. A detailed account of how they were discovered historically can provide one answer to that. Results like the Frobenius or Hurwitz theorems, phrased as answers to questions, can provide another. To assume that complex developments in the history of mathematics were "inevitable" is indeed boring & limiting

Comment: For clarity, 4ions = quaternions. I ran out of room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the paper *Hamilton's Discovery of Quaternions* by *B. L. VAN DER WAERDEN*, the author lists the criteria Hamilton was looking to satisfy from his algebra:

- They must define a finite-dimensional unital algebra over $\mathbb R$. This led him to adopt the notation $a + bi + cj$ for the elements of such an algebra.
- Assume a hypothetical 3-dimensional number system where the numbers are of the form $z = a + bi + cj$. Hamilton defined $|z|$ to be $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$ by generalising the same operation over the complex numbers. He wanted this operation to satisfy the identity $|wz| = |w| |z|$.

The combination of these criteria define precisely the *normed unital algebras*. By Hurwitz's theorem, the only algebras satisfying these criteria are $\mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb H, \mathbb O$, where the last symbol denotes the octonions.

Comment: Reading over van der Waerden's paper, this answer is dubious. He actually lists the criteria as follows: "He required, first, that it be possible to multiply out term by term; and second, that the length of the
product of the vectors be equal to the product of the lengths." Putting it in modern terms is silly when the whole purpose is to get historical insight into his process. If you want to understand Hamilton's reasoning, you have to think like Hamilton. If you want your own derivation, there's no need to consider Hamilton at all.

Answer (score 3):

When I have time later I might return to this and try to provide additional exposition directly addressing your question, maybe quote something relevant from Crowe's [**A History of Vector Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com//dp/0486679101) (a book I've been reading the past 2 months; I'm now a little more than half-way through it). However, for now I thought it would be useful to provide some older books (and a couple of papers by Hamilton) to look at. As for the books, besides glancing through their table of contents, reading their prefaces, etc., I also recommend reading reviews of these books, which are easy to find by googling the author's last name and the book's title in google-books (date-restrict from the publication date to about 5 years later). I’ve included links to the book reviews I know about.

Every link below is freely available on the internet, at least where I am. Probably all of the books are also freely available online at the Internet Archive (easiest way: google the book's title, maybe author's last name if the title is fairly generic, along with the "word" archive.org), but probably not all of the reviews can be found elsewhere online (freely or otherwise). If you really want to dive into the older literature on quaternions, you’ll want to make use of Macfarlane’s **Bibliography of Quaternions and Allied Systems of Mathematics** (1904).

***1843*** [*On a new species of imaginary quantities connected with a theory of quaternions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9WTtoOfnUWoC&pg=PA424) by Hamilton

***1844*** [*Additional researches in the theory of quaternions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=B7xJAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA1) by Hamilton

***1853*** [**Lectures on Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ein9159_XecC) by Hamilton

> review in [*The North American Review*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QjoAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA223) (a review known as one of the most over-the-top-with-praise review ever of a math book)

***1866*** [**Elements of Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=b2stAAAAYAAJ) by Hamilton

> review in [*Philosophical Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SELRHNvOfcQC&pg=PA308)

***1867*** [**An Elementary Treatise on Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=PpIKAAAAYAAJ) by Tait

***1873*** [**An Elementary Treatise on Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=TwkXAAAAYAAJ) by Tait (2nd edition)

> review in [*Philosophical Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=61AwAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA364)

***1876*** [**Introduction to Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=tFEDAAAAQAAJ) by Kelland/Tait

review in [*Nature*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JrhCAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA137)

***1881*** [**Elements of Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=uc83AAAAMAAJ) by Hardy

review in [*The Ohio Educational Monthly*](https://books.google.com/books?id=eiMbAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA372); review in [*Wisconsin Journal of Education*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gPEBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA521); review in [*Science*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2900879); review in [*The Westminster Review*](https://books.google.com/books?id=s1pDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA255); review in [*Popular Science Monthly*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KCIDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA708)

***1882*** [**Introduction to Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=xK0AAAAAMAAJ) by Kelland/Tait (2nd edition)

***1890*** [**An Elementary Treatise on Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=CGZLAAAAMAAJ) by Tait (3rd edition)

***1894*** [**The Outlines of Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=MkQ6AAAAMAAJ) by Hime

> review in [*Minutes of Proceedings of the Royal Artillery Institution*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JPRBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA297); review in [*Educational Times*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ar8gAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA267); review in [*Mathematical Gazette*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7CfWAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA16); review in [*The Academy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yFU_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA196) (begins middle of middle column); review in [*Philosophical Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TZAOAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA499); review in [*Nature*](https://books.google.com/books?id=f6FFAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA76); review in [*American Mathematical Monthly*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RHHxAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA34); review in [*Science*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BzRDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA699) (begins middle of right column)

***1896*** [**A Primer of Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=kpxRAAAAMAAJ) by Hathaway

> review in [*The Literary Era*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3TDZAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA113); review in [*Physical Review*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rR_OAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA421); review in [*Science*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BzRDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA700) (top-most paragraph on left column of p. 700); review in [*Electrical Engineering*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EqZIAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA112)

***1899*** [**Elements of Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q5IKAAAAYAAJ) by Hamilton (2nd edition, Volume I, edited by Joly)

***1901*** [**Elements of Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=RJIKAAAAYAAJ) by Hamilton (2nd edition, Volume II, edited by Joly)

review in [*Nature*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UMkKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA387) (Vol. I); review in [*Philosophical Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WXwvAQAAIAAJ) (Vol. I & II); review in [*Science*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_X8CAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA65) (Vol. I & II); review in [*Nature*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7soKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA206) (Vol. II)

***1904*** [**Introduction to Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=ny87AQAAIAAJ) by Kelland/Tait (3rd edition; prepared by Knott)

> review in [*Nature*](https://books.google.com/books?id=33YCAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA604); review in [*The Cambridge Review*](https://books.google.com/books?id=iLJNAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA284); review in [*Mathematical Gazette*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ulDWAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA42)

***1904*** [**Bibliography of Quaternions and Allied Systems of Mathematics**](https://books.google.com/books?id=CkE6AAAAMAAJ) by Macfarlane

> review in [*Nature*](https://books.google.com/books?id=y5NFAAAAYAAJ); review in [*Philosophical Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9k8EAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA758); review in [*Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society*](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1906-13-01/S0002-9904-1906-01411-2/S0002-9904-1906-01411-2.pdf)

***1905*** [**A Manual of Quaternions**](https://books.google.com/books?id=AC8PAAAAIAAJ) by Joly

review in [*Mathematical Gazette*](https://books.google.com/books?id=maDxAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA229); review in [*Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society*](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1905-11-10/S0002-9904-1905-01259-3/S0002-9904-1905-01259-3.pdf); review in [*Nature*](https://books.google.com/books?id=eZVFAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA121); review in [*The School World*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SRQLAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA237); review in [*Technics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=R3xGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA474)

Answer (score 2):

You are right when you "think that the above three notions did not get studied until after Hamilton presented the quaternions".

Hamilton wanted to generalize complex numbers to have a tool to represent rotations of 3-space, similar to representation of rotations of the plane
by complex numbers of absolute value 1. Since rotations in 3 space do not commute, it was clear that commutativity of multiplication had to be rejected. He found first that there is no reasonable generalization in dimension 3, and then found a proper generalization in dimension 4.

Comment: Unlikely. The problem is that a quaternion is not a rotation of 3D space. The reason being that that $q$ and $-q$ act as the same rotation on 3D space.

Comment: Sorry, but this disagrees with the paper I found on the topic and my understanding of the relationship between the algebra $\mathbb H$ and the Lie group $SO(3)$. Hence my downvote.

Comment: What you say is correct, but nevertheless quaternions are useful in representing rotations, and I am sure this is what Hamilton had in mind.

Comment: The criterion $|wz| = |w| |z|$ has some connection to rotations, I suppose. The connection being that if $q$ has unit length, and $r$ is a n-dimensional vector represented as an element of our hypothetical normed unital algebra, then $|qr| = |r|$; so by the polarisation identity $q$ must be an orthogonal transformation of n-dimensional space, and by further consideration, moreso a rotation.

Comment: I suppose his hypothetical triples would've been useful for representing rotations in 3D space. But they don't exist. Using his criteria, a 4-dimensional generalisation like the quaternions would only be useful for representing (some) rotations of 4D space. I guess it follows that if you have a formalism for representing some of the rotations of 4D space, or *all* rotations of 4D space depending on how you use it, then a restriction to the special case of 3D rotations should follow.

Comment: I would like to rescind my downvote. I may have misread this answer.

Comment: Your point about rotations of 3D space (or n-dimensional space for n > 2) not commuting is plausible as a reason for accepting non-commutativity.

Answer (score 0):

In B. L. van der Waerden's article (linked in your own answer), [Hamilton's Discovery of Quaternions](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689449), the history of Hamilton and quaternions is laid out clearly, based on Hamilton's publications and correspondence. In brief (although that article is already brief), first note that Hamilton "knew and used the geometric representation of complex numbers," but in publications "he emphasized the definition of complex numbers as the couple $(a,b)$ which followed definite rules for addition and multiplication." He posed the problem:

> "*To find how number-triplets $(a,b,c)$ are to be multiplied in analogy to couples $(a,b)$*."

Van der Waerden continues:

> In analogy to the complex numbers $(a + ib)$ Hamilton wrote his triplets as $(a + bi + cj)$. He represented his unit vectors $1$, $i$, $j$ as mutually perpendicular "directed segments" of unit length in space. Later Hamilton himself used the word vector, which I also shall use in the following. Hamilton then sought to represent products such as $(a + bi + cj)(x + yi + zj)$ again as vectors in the same space. **He required, first, that it be possible to multiply out term by term; and second, that the length of the product of the vectors be equal to the product of the lengths.** This latter rule was called the "law of the moduli" by Hamilton.

(emphasis mine)

Which answers the question. The rest of the article explains how Hamilton determined the necessity for four dimensions instead of three based on these criteria, and how he arrived at the relations for quaternions.